# Bulk namespace rename

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am making an ERP using ASP.NET Web Forms. I started working on this a while back and successfully completed a version. My project's root namespace is EPERP. So I have other namespaces like EPERP.DataAccessLayer, EPERP.Controllers, etc.

Now, due to client demands, I have divided my project into several parts. I have divided the code layer into one part, and divided the view layer into multiple parts based on client requirements.

The ugly part is that, I did this by opening empty web application projects in visual studio and then copying the relevant view files into that project. That is how I have divided one project into four.

Since my code part is a separate project, all my view related projects reference the dll created from that project.

The problem is that, all projects have the same namespace. So my view related projects have root namespace EPERP, and they reference a dll that has a root namespace EPERP.

None of my projects have the same files, but sometimes I get this error when running my project that a file is ambigous since it is specified in both assemblies.

In any case, keeping the same namespace was a really bad decision.

How can I change the namespace of my project so that it affects the subnamespaces as well?

Comment: Just use the "Replace All" function, and let it do the replacing of "namespace EPERP" in "Current Project". Using that "Replace All" function will also rename your "subnamespaces" as well, while keeping the rest intact, as in the ".DataAcessLayer".

Answer (score 1):

That's why I always say that [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a must have for all .NET programmers.

In your post, you didn't say nothing about using 3rd tools, so make sure that each project has it's own default namespace (Project Properties -> Application), then right click at Solution -> Refactor -> Adjust Namespaces.

ReSharper will take care of all `using` needed due new namespace.

And I case you're using folder, it will treat the namespace like you spected, ex.: `namespace MyNamespace.EPERP.MyFolder { ... }` will become `namespace MyNamespace.EPERP.MyNewModule.MyFolder { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you Replace All through VS

> (shortcut : ctrl+shift+H)

but make sure that there is nothing named after the namespace as as substring or something.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is better to do the renaming manually

Answer (score 0):

Open a file under the namespace EPERP.DataAccessLayer in your visual studio, and then change it to SOMETHINGNEW.DataAccessLayer. Once you do this you will see a small Red Box like under the word  SOMETHINGNEW.DataAccessLayer, when you click that red thing you will see the option "Rename 'EPERP' to 'SOMETHINGNEW'", when you select this option it will rename all the references of EPERP to SOMETHINGNEW.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a small utility to do that than to do it manually. And if you are feeling a little lazy then use free tools like notepad++ to recursively find and replace namespace declaration across .cs files in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a completely automatic way to do what you are asking for.
You need to take some steps to do it, and some of the steps can be automated.

I will try to provide an answer and share experience at the same time.

First, you need a way to identify places in the files, where the namespace is actually specified, and the first file type to discover is `.csproj` files.
Open it as a text file in your favorite text editor. If you need to open it in Visual Studio you need to unload the project first using the right mouse button context menu in the Solution Explorer window. When you have unloaded your project this way, you can edit it using the same context menu. You can reload the project as you finished editing it.

Of course you should backup the entire solution folder before you make any change to the text files this way.

Before the backup you should exit Visual Studio. This way you make sure everything is saved on disk, because Visual Studio does not always play nice when you change something manually, and could eventually mess things up and override the file on disk with it's own version which is in memory.

Now that you have opended the .csproj file in a text editor, you are actually looking at the msbuild file format, which is in XML.
Search for the `RootNamespace` property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This is the property you need to change, if you taken this path (editing .csproj as a text file).

You can also do the same specifying the Default Namespace in project properties in Visual Studio, but it's important to know that you have control, as all the project files essentially are just XML files, editable as text.

This is the first step of changing the namespace "completely", and you can't skip it, if you want all of the embedded resources and code generation to work correctly.

Second step is to change the namespace declarations and references in all of the project's .cs files, including regular cs files, and Designer.cs files, generated by aspnet designer.

You can use the "Replace in files" command, accessible with `Ctrl-Shift-F` to replace the text in all the .cs files where you declared or referenced that namespace.

Another option is to use ReSharper's "Adjust Namespaces" command, and I recommend to use ReSharper for all Visual Studio/C# development tasks.

Then you can browse for the namespace reference in all the files in solution folder and discover all the file xml text file types where it is referenced, such as .resx files. Those should be handled by ReSharper also.

One more thing to note, that you might wish to delete the .suo and .user files upon completion of previous steps and also clean ReSharper caches. It's a good idea to do this step after each manual editing of project files in text editor.